# Stuck at an integral

Tags: integration

So I'm trying to find a volume of a surface and a cylinder. I managed to do it with cylindrical coordinates. But I wanted to try to without it, but the integral is seriously hard for me. So the integral was

$$V=\int^2_{-2}\int^\sqrt{4-x^2}_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int^{4-x^2}_0dzdydz$$

Using the symmetri and the fact that our function is even

$$V=4\int^2_0\int^\sqrt{4-x^2}\int^{4-x^2}_0dzdydx$$

I manged the last part

$$V=4\int^2_0(4-x^2)\left(\sqrt{4-x^2}\right)dx$$

I first used integration by parts where $u = (4-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$and $dv=1$ and ended up with 
$$I = 4\left(x\left(4-x^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\int-3x^2\sqrt{4-x^2}dx\right)$$

This is where I'm stuck, clearly u-substitution wouldn't work. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

So I am trying on using integration by parts again, by letting $u=3x^2$ and $dv=\sqrt{4-x^2}$

Comment: Little bug: $dv=dx$...

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the integral:
$$I=4\int_0^2 {\left(4-x^2\right)}^{\frac{3}{2}} \; dx$$
Let $x=2\sin{t}$:
$$I=64\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \cos^4{t} \; dt$$
Using [Walli's integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals):
$$I=64 \cdot \frac{3\pi}{16}=\boxed{12\pi}$$

If you don't know Walli's integral then you can just use the reduction formula twice:
$$\cos^4{x}={\left(\cos^2{x}\right)}^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos{2x}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\cos{2x}}{2}+\frac{\cos^2{2x}}{4}=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{\cos{2x}}{2}+\frac{\cos{4x}}{8}$$

Comment: thanks for the answer. I didn't get very far when using partial integration again. But I don't see how if u let $x=2\sin t$ that u get $\cos^4t$, shouldn't it be $\cos^3t$? since $1-\sin^2t=cos^2t\Rightarrow \left(\cos^2y\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: Don't forget $dx=2\cos{t} dt$

Comment: oh yeah, true. Thanks, i'll try using this approach now!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For integral $\space  \int R \left(  x, \sqrt{a^2 - x^2 } \right) dx \space$ use this substitution: $\space x=a \sin t.$